# Issue with Bcrypt not verifying correctly

Tags: php, validation, pdo, cryptography, authorization

I'm using a script that [ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell) wrote called [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). I thought I followed his instructions correctly, but I cannot seem to get my password verified using `password_verify($password, $hash)`.

The hashed password saved in my database is;

```
$2y$10$zYpSzIj7kTPv3H7wDI/uXSYqi1se46b38uumP6SM4XGMmsjU3q
```

I'm using PDO to grab my hashed password and using `password_verify($password, $hash)` to compare what the login form is posting. It's my understanding that BRCYPT is not a hashing function so `password_verify($password, $hash)` will do it's magic. I have no idea how the salt is created, but I would think it creates a custom salt for every new password, but how it can compare it to my saved password baffles me. How does it match the correct salt with the password? This whole not saving the salt in my database kind of confuses me, lol. Here is the code I'm using;

**bcrypt**

```
if($login->verifyip($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
{
    require_once 'password.php'; //password_compat supplied file

    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $password   = $_POST['password'];
    $dbpassword = $login->GetPassword($username); // pull saved password from db

    // verify posted password with saved password
    if(password_verify($dbpassword, $password))
    {
        echo 'verified';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not verified';
    }
}
```

**PDO**

```
public function GetPassword($username)
{
    $passwordSQL = 'CALL get_password(:_user)'; // using stored procedure
    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('my login stuff');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $password = $pdo->prepare($passwordSQL);
        $password->bindParam(':_user',$username);
        $password->execute();
        $fetch = $password->fetchColumn(0);
        $password->closeCursor();
        return $fetch;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
         return 'error' . $e->getMessage();
         exit();
    }        
}
```

**I removed $hash like blender suggested.**

Thanks for having a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`password_verify`'s arguments are the other way around:

```
password_verify($password, $dbpassword)
```

As for how it works, the hash is of this form:

```
$<algorithm>$<cost>$<salt>/<hash>
```

So from the hash:

```
$2y$10$zYpSzIj7kTPv3H7wDI/uXSYqi1se46b38uumP6SM4XGMmsjU3q
```

You can see that the cost is `10`, the salt is `zYpSzIj7kTPv3H7wDI` and that `bcrypt(salt + password)` is `uXSYqi1se46b38uumP6SM4XGMmsjU3q`.

`password_verify` extracts that information from your supplied hash and just checks if `bcrypt(salt + password) == hash`.

Comment: *HUGE FACE SMACK* - WOW, it amazes me how little my attention to detail is. Thank you, works like a champ!

Comment: Do you see anything else I could *tweak*?

Comment: @Mike: You could get rid of the line that starts with `$has = ...`.

Comment: Ah, because the password_verify probably hashes it again ... correct?

Comment: @Mike: It hashes `$password` with `$dbpassword`'s salt.