# PHP - password_verify issue

Tags: php, mysql, hash, php-password-hash

I have been scratching my head on this for over 2 hours. I have researched articles on stackoverflow including:

- [Issue with Bcrypt not verifying correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246082/issue-with-bcrypt-not-verifying-correctly)
- [php password_hash and password_verify issues no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855715/php-password-hash-and-password-verify-issues-no-match)
- [`password_verify` call returning false for correct password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090481/password-verify-call-returning-false-for-correct-password)

And I havent been able to correct my issue. I would appreciate some guidance on how much of an idiot I am being:

**Function to insert data into MySQL database:**

```
function insertUser($userObj) {
    $query = $this->databaseConnection->getStntPrepare()->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO user(username, userpassword) VALUES (?,?);");
    $username = $userObj->getUsername();
    $password = password_hash('testing1234', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $query->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
}
```

**Verification of user login by retrieving data from MySQL:**

```
function findUser($userObj) {
    $query = $this->databaseConnection->getStntPrepare()->prepare(
            "SELECT userid, userpassword 
                FROM user 
                WHERE username=?");

    $pass = 'testing1234'
    $query->bind_param('s', $userObj->getUsername());
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($userid, $hash);

    while ($query->fetch()) {

        if (password_verify($pass, $hash)) {
            echo 'Password is valid!';
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid password.';
        }
    }
}
```

When run I get 'Invalid password.'

**When I do the below without inserting into database then retrieving:**

```
$hash = password_hash('testing1234', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
if (password_verify('testing1234', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

I get 'Password is valid!'

I believe my problem is something to do with single and double quotes and the interpretation of dollar sign ($) in the password field, as a variable instead of literal (as one of the articles suggests) when storing/retrieving from MySQL database - however I haven't had any luck in resolving. Below is the hash value of 'testing1234':

$2y$10$1/oQEuYX67n.U3usxH.7tenNq7hT2dKyBSIZsy5xR3W

Comment: What data type is your `userpassword` field in the database? What value do you see if you `echo $hash` just before you call `password_verify()`? (Also: try `echo strlen($hash)`...)

Comment: Nice catch! varchar(40) was the problem. Extended it and now sorted.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in the database - nothing to do with password_verify or password_hash. Datatype had a maximum amount of characters (only defined to 40 as I was made to by MySQL when creating tables). Moved to 60 and no more issues.

Comment: why you should always run strict mode ;) would have made the problem obvious.