# Returning True or False from database

Tags: php, mysql

I've just started doing a bit of PHP coding and was wondering how to do a function that returns TRUE or FALSE when the username and password are checked against the database. If they are there I want to return as TRUE and if they aren't... FALSE. My tables called 'P_USER'.

**So far I have this**:

```
<?php

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);

  $username = $_POST["username"];
  //echo $username;

  $password = $_POST["password"];
  //echo $username;

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM P_USER");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891355/php-password-verify-issue

Comment: Stop using the `mysql` PHP extension (function names starting with `mysql_`). It is [deprecated and will be removed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) in the near future. Consider learning the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions instead.

Answer (score 1):

Database cannot return true or false as you want. But there is a work around.

You can check the value of username and password and if it matches then the query will return 1 else it will return 0.

The query is:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM P_USER WHERE username = $username and password = $password;
```

Provided that the username is unique in you table.

Then you can check the result of the query and then perform the action as desired.

Comment: Please add link for Mysql Injection, it's safier.